# Does numpy.where behave erratically for high-dimensional arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

... or is it my fault?

I have a seven-dimensional array, `shape=(5,5,5,5,5,5,5)`, filled mostly with zeros and a few (~10) non-zero elements.

I observe that in some cases, `numpy.where` does not return the values one would expect the tuple of arrays to have. The shape is correct, i.e. for a seven-dimensional array with 10 non-zero elements, a tuple with 7 elements (one for each axis), each being a 10-element array (with the coordinates along this axis). Sometimes all of these arrays are the same, sometimes they are not.

I run Windows 10 and this is my python installation:

> Python 3.5.3 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Feb 22 2017, 21:28:42) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Here is some code that reproduces the error:

```
import numpy as np

for i in range(5,11):
    print("dims:", i)
    A = np.zeros([5]*i)
    print("shape:", A.shape)
    for j in range(10):
        c = np.random.randint(low=0, high=5, size=i)
        A[tuple(c)] = j
        print(tuple(c), ":", j)
    print(np.where(A))
```

Sample output for 5 dimensions:

```
(0, 4, 1, 2, 1) : 0
(2, 0, 3, 1, 4) : 1
(3, 2, 0, 0, 4) : 2
(0, 4, 0, 2, 0) : 3
(4, 2, 4, 4, 3) : 4
(3, 3, 4, 3, 1) : 5
(1, 2, 1, 3, 4) : 6
(0, 4, 0, 4, 0) : 7
(4, 4, 0, 4, 2) : 8
(4, 0, 0, 2, 3) : 9
(array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4], dtype=int64), array([4, 4, 2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 2, 4], dtype=int64), array([0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0], dtype=int64), array([2, 4, 3, 1, 0, 3, 2, 4, 4], dtype=int64), array([0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 1, 3, 3, 2], dtype=int64))
```

and the output for 10 dimensions, on the same run – note how all arrays in the result tuple are the same:

```
(0, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 3, 2, 1) : 0
(0, 2, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 4) : 1
(4, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3) : 2
(2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 4) : 3
(4, 0, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 0, 4, 0) : 4
(3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4) : 5
(2, 4, 0, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 2) : 6
(1, 1, 0, 4, 1, 3, 2, 0, 3, 2) : 7
(4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 4, 1) : 8
(0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2) : 9
(array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4], dtype=int64), array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4], dtype=int64), array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4], dtype=int64), array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4], dtype=int64), array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4], dtype=int64), array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4], dtype=int64), array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4], dtype=int64), array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4], dtype=int64), array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4], dtype=int64), array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4], dtype=int64))
```

Sometimes the error occurs at >=8 dimensions, sometimes at 9.

Is this a problem with my understanding of `numpy.where`, a bug in `numpy`, or an issue with my python installation or system?

Comment: I __cannot__ reproduce this behavior on my Linux system `Python 3.5.4 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Aug 14 2017, 13:26:58) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux` ... at least up to an array of 3^18 elements.

Comment: It seems like __an update__ from `numpy-1.13.0-py35_0` to `numpy-1.13.1-py35_0` did the trick. I can now not reproduce the error for arrays up to 5^12 or 3^18 elements.